# Get the full network path of a file on a Mac - terminal

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to get the network file page e.g. `smb://server.local/tech/file.pdf`

You can see this information on a files "Get info" window but I can't see a way of getting this with the command line (or even Applescript).

**Edit:**
I currently have this:

```
on open filePath
    set filePath to POSIX path of filePath
    set the clipboard to filePath as text
end open
```

But it only copied the mounted path and not the smb:// path.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, almost all attributes of a file/folder can be retrieved with AppleScript (i.e. `kind of this_file`). So, unless I'm mistaken, you should be able to `get network file page of refToSomeFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automator will do this.

> - Ask For Servers
> - Copy to Clipboard

[image: Full Network Path]

[Download it here.](http://cl.ly/2P28093d1X2E081A1G0e)